# Running Code on page leave [Actionscript]

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, shutdown-hook

How can I run code in Actionscript 3 when a page with my flash object is... well... I'm not sure of the term.

When the webpage is left and the flash applet is exited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Flash has built-in functionality to catch this type of event. You might try a javascript solution. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event). By doing so, you could implement a flash object callback using Flash's [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) at the time the user leaves your page.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that if the reason for running code on page leave is to communicate with a server and/or you are making a game to be put up on other portals and you cannot modify their javascript, save whatever you need to save every X seconds, or better, every time something major changes (eg you competed a level / new highscore). This way, if your game/browser/os crashes progress is not lost.