# How to change the location.href property dynamically through jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change the href of a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="home" onclick="location.href='index.php'">Home</button>
```

I tried this:

```
$('#home').prop("href" , "home.php");
```

PHP:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="home" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $link; ?>'">Home</button>
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Button code:  <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="home" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $link; ?>'">Home</button>

Comment: Thats because the `href` isn't an attribute of your `button`. It is a part of your `onclick` handler.

Comment: It doesn't work because you using onclick, not href....

Comment: If it has to be an onclick, replace where it navigates to with a variable, then edit the variable when you need to change where it redirects to.

Comment: Why aren't you using an anchor tag as semantically what you are doing is incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change window.location.href in JavaScript and then execute more JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209626/how-to-change-window-location-href-in-javascript-and-then-execute-more-js)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `#home` around an anchor `<a>` tag then you can change it like so:

Edit: As @putvande's comments below suggest that I cannot have a button inside an anchor tag since it's semantically incorrect, I will change the `<button>` tag to a `<span>` with class `btn`.

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
    <span class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="home">Home</span>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#home').parent().attr('href', 'home.php');
</script>
```

Comment: This is semantically incorrect. You can't have a button inside an anchor tag.

Comment: @putvande Thanks. TIL. I will modify my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#home")[0].onclick = null;
$("#home").click(function() { location.href="home.php";});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is `attr()` not `.prop()`

JS:

```
$('#home').attr("href" , "home.php");
```

See fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/epL9gb6t/

Comment: He's using a button, not an anchor tag.

Comment: It is unclear whether he is referring to a semantic `<button>` or a button using an a tag `<a class="btn>`. Given that he has an HREF, it's fair to assume it's an anchor, hence not worthy of a downvote..

Comment: P.s. this was before he posted his source HTML code.