# Call Java component from JavaScript and retrieve value

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket, wicket-1.6

I am trying to call a Wicket component's method from JavaScript and receive a value from this method which I want to use in the remaining bit of the JavaScript function which I used to call the component. However, I only seem to be able to call a Wicket component without waiting for it to produce a result.

More explicitly, I want to implement an `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior` which allows me to conditionally warn a user when he or she is leaving a page. This condition is for now determined by some `OuterClass.shouldWarn` method. However, even though this method gets called in my example below, I seem to be both unable to wait for a result of this method as well as I am unable to return some sort of result at all. Instead, the JavaScript just continues in its execution concurrently to the Java method call.

I hope the (not correctly running) example below clarifies my question:

```
 class PageExitWarningBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

        @Override
        protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.appendJavaScript("return " + 
                (OuterClass.this.shouldWarn() ? "false" : "true"));
        }

        @Override
        public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {

            String callbackFunktion = String.format(
                    "Wicket.Event.add(window, 'beforeunload', function( e ) {%n"
                          + "if( e ) { e.returnValue = '%s'; }%n"
                          + "var attrs = { 'u': '%s', 'c': '%s', 'ep': { } };%n"
                          + "Wicket.Ajax.get( attrs );%n"
                          + "return false;%n;"
                          + "});",
                    this.getCallbackUrl(),
                    OuterClass.this.getMarkupId());

            response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript(callbackFunktion, 
                 "remind-of-running-task"));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is an easier way to intercept a page exit event than implementing your own AjaxBehavior:

Try implementing the following Behavior:

```
public class PageExitWarningBehavior extends Behavior {

  private boolean shouldWarn = false;

  @Override
  public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(component, response);
    if (shouldWarn) {
      response.render(new OnDomReadyHeaderItem("window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {"
    + "var message = 'Your confirmation message goes here.'," 
        + "e = e || window.event;" + "if (e) {"
    + "e.returnValue = message;" + "}" + "return message;" + "};"));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onEvent(Component component, IEvent<?> event) {
    super.onEvent(component, event);
    if (event.getPayload() instanceof PageExitWarningEvent) {
      PageExitWarningEvent exitEvent = (PageExitWarningEvent) event.getPayload();
    this.shouldWarn = exitEvent.isPageExitWarningEnabled();
    }
  }
}
```

In the renderHead method you conditionally add a simple javascript that triggers the browser to show a confirmation dialog when leaving the page (the javascript code is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)).

In the onEvent method we listen if some other Wicket component has sent an PageExitWarningEvent to inform us that a warning should be displayed at all. You can send such an event from any Wicket component (such as a link or button) like this:

```
send(HomePage.this, Broadcast.BREADTH, new PageExitWarningEvent(true));
```

The PageExitWarningEvent class looks like this:

```
public class PageExitWarningEvent {

  private boolean pageExitWarningEnabled = false;

  public PageExitWarningEvent(boolean pageExitWarningEnabled) {
    this.setPageExitWarningEnabled(pageExitWarningEnabled);
  }

  public boolean isPageExitWarningEnabled() {
    return pageExitWarningEnabled;
  }

  public void setPageExitWarningEnabled(boolean pageExitWarningEnabled) {
    this.pageExitWarningEnabled = pageExitWarningEnabled;
  }

}
```

Let me know if that meets your requirements.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I've played around a bit and created a working example at https://github.com/thombergs/wicket-pageexitwarning-example.