# How can I implement a Close Tab Listener of my Browser Tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

Is it possible to catch the following event?

1. A user closes a tab where my app is running in?
2. A user closes a browser where my app is running in?

How can I implement a listener for these events?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for an onbeforeunload event

See Eli Grey's answer below

[Intercept page exit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)