# blank on refreshed webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a webpage

sample.html

and when I click something

it goes

sample.html#bro

and when I refresh(f5) it

it still sample.html#bro
and shows its content

how can I remove the #bro

with just refreshing any idea?

btw this is the code i use

```
<a href="#div1">Div one</a>
<a href="#div2">Div two</a>
<a href="#div3">Div three</a>
<a href="#div4">Div four</a>

<div id="content">
<div id="div1">This is div one</div>
<div id="div2">This is div two</div>
<div id="div3">This is div three</div>
<div id="div4">This is div four</div>
</div>
```

the css is

```
#content > div {
display: none;
}

#content > div:target {
display: block;
}
```

any thoughts on when refreshed the content will reset or blank

Answer (score 0):

I think You need two things. You can try this.

1. Event when page is getting unload

[Intercept page exit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)

2. Inside this event remove the hash and reload the page

[How to remove the hash from window.location with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh)

But there is a problem, I am not sure what will happen when you want to move to another page from this page. I think then also your page will get refreshed.