# Intercept page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im scraping a website and Im trying to redirect to another website if people click on a link so I injected some javascript:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {

for (var ls = document.links, numLinks = ls.length, i=0; i<numLinks; i++){
    ls[i].href= 'http://mywebsite.com/test.php?url=' + this;
}

});
```

It works, but it only works on actual links `<a href..>`. Sometimes a click on an element will act as a link do to some javascript, I also would like to capture that 'event'. It has me thinking about  `XMLHttpRequest` if I Im not mistaken the browser has a built in object called `XMLHttp` object, which one could use to intercept ajax calls:

```
(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async) {

//do something...
```

So my question is: Does anything similar exist for listening and altering outgoing URL's?

Answer (score 2):

Just so I'm clear on this, whenever somebody clicks on a link, you want to figure out what that URL is, alter it, then redirect the user to your own URL?

```
$('a').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

`preventDefault()` will stop the page from redirecting.

At this point, `url` will be the URL string, and you can do whatever you want to it. To redirect the user, either use `window.location.href` or `window.location.replace`.

JSfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/JQ5qC/

Comment: What if some javascript is generating the URL like so: http://jsfiddle.net/JQ5qC/1/

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. When is JavaScipt generating a URL? In your example, you're simply redirecting the page to CNET on click, anywhere in the HTML page.

Comment: 'simply redirecting the page' Yes by javascript which holds the 'URL'. So the question is; how do I intercept this URL and change it before leaving for its destination?

Comment: Do you want to intercept the page redirect when somebody clicks on a hyperlink, or intercept it at all times when the URL changes?

Comment: I think intercept it at all times when the URL changes. Which obviously includes 'intercept the page redirect when somebody clicks on a hyperlink'

Comment: I haven't done anything with this personally, but you should look into window.onbeforeunload

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event