# log the alert box that pops up when leaving a page

Tags: javascript, alert, onbeforeunload

I want to log alert boxes that pop up when I leave a page(when onbeforeunload, onunload or any other event is triggered while leaving a page). So I have overwritten alert function to record alert function invocations. Then I set window.location to some other url to navigate away from the page. But the problem is that when window.location is executed, it destroys my custom alert function and I can not log it any more. 
Any suggestion on how to solve it?
**Edit**
The page that I want to log its alert box is  a third party's page. In order to inspect it, a scrip code is injected to the header of the page like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script> window.alert = function(str){console.log(‘alert is called: ’ + str);}</script>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload=function(){alert(“you are leaving!”);}>
Sample page
</body>
</html>
```

When I execute window.location='http://google.com' on this page, an alert box pops up, instead of calling that overwritten alert function.

Comment: Some code will help to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

This could save some efforts catching the leave page event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = "Your confirmation message goes here.",
  e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
  }

  // For Safari
  return message;
};
```

the answer is not my property, you can find more here:

[Intercept page exit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)

Comment: I don't want to change onbeforeunload handler of the page, I want to log onbeforeunload or any other event that  would be trigger on leaving a page.