# Saving data on `beforeunload` in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to save user changes to a form on the server with AJAX on tab/window close.

This is a similar question:
[Intercept page exit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)

I am using this code :

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', beforeUnload);
```

...and it seems to work fine except for when using IE11.

It seems that when the user verification alert pops up in IE11, every JS piece of code that was previously running gets halted (and my data is not sent over the wire).
So, if the user chooses to leave, everything is gone.

Has anybody made it work on that browser?
Is it possible?

**EDIT :**

I see now that it works sometimes and it fails on others.

When it fails, it starts the AJAX call (it hits the breakpoint at that point), but never gets in the success/fail function... (and I see nothing being sent when using Fiddler)

In summary, it first hits the AJAX call breakpoint, it then displays the confirmation dialog, and when you choose to leave the page nothing gets sent... :(

Comment: I think the smart thing to do would be to just ignore Internet Explorer.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Yes, I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this method of saving data is not reliable and it is working only by pure luck.

Also, the synchronous XHR is marked as deprecated by now, so it's not a good idea to use that either.

So, I guess the web is not meant to work this way...