# handling the back button or closing tab

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on online examination system using **php and mysql** and I am new to this programing language. I want to prevent the one taking the exam from leaving the questions page by clicking on the back button or accidentally closing the tab. I want to warn the user that all his work will be lost if he leaves the page and if he decides to leave then he/she will get zero marks on the exam.

**I have found many people providing solutions to this problem but none of them worked with me, so,it would be nice  if any one can help with a simple code that can do what I need using javascript**

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the `onbeforeunload` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercept page exit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)

Comment: If solutions to duplicate questions don't work for you, please tell us which solutions you tried and **why** they didn't work for you (what happened that should have happened, and any error message you received).

Comment: @AndrewMyers  I tried what you provided,but the back button doesn't work once the page is loaded directly. Actually the warning can appear  after I click a link on my page ,only after that the back button starts to function, but if i click the back button directly after  loading the page it takes me to the previous page without warning or alert box. Any ideas??