# Cakephp 3.6.14: Confirmation message if form is incomplete and user leaves page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am using `cakephp-3.6.14` and I have this form:

```
<div class="customers form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
<?= $this->Form->create($customer) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Edit Customer') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('company');
        echo $this->Form->control('name');
        echo $this->Form->control('surname');
        echo $this->Form->control('tel');
        echo $this->Form->control('mob');
        echo $this->Form->control('email');
        echo $this->Form->control('customer_type_id', ['options' => $customerTypes, 'empty' => true]);
        echo $this->Form->control('business_type_id', ['options' => $businessTypes, 'empty' => true]);
        echo $this->Form->control('business_name');
        echo $this->Form->control('balance');
        echo $this->Form->control('birthday', ['empty' => true]);
        echo $this->Form->control('notes');
        echo $this->Form->control('user_assigned');
        echo $this->Form->control('created_by');
        echo $this->Form->control('created_date', ['empty' => true]);
        echo $this->Form->control('modified_by');
        echo $this->Form->control('modified_date', ['empty' => true]);
        echo $this->Form->control('Address');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?></br></br>
```

Is it possible to show a confirmation message like "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" if the user has started completing the form and accidentally (by clicking on a menu item) redirects to another page?

I want the confirmation message to be displayed only if the user has completed at least one field of the form. Which is not answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercept page exit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event)

Comment: @Cid I want the confirmation message to be displayed only if the user has completed at least one field of the form. Which is not answered in this question you provided as duplicate.

Comment: Nothing stops you from checking the values in the inputs in that function

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this [are-you-sure_plugin](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure)