# How to update status in db on webpage leave/closed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to update status flag 1 if user working on say 'XYZ' page and immediately update 0 when user leaves this page

i can able to update flag 1 by simple update query with linq in respective controller when user enters in.

but the problem is how to update flag 0 when user leaves or closes browser window directly

i tried adding following code :

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        ----------AJAX FUNCTION TO UPDATE DATA HERE--------------
    });
};
```

But the problem is how to get callback of this alert-box
[see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOF8R.png)

Comment: Can you provide us some code ?

Comment: You can use SignalR and handle the OnDisconnected event : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#connectionlifetime

Comment: @FrancoisBorgies see the edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't be certain that this will work consistently just by using clientside functionality, as there could be many ways a session ends, which would NOT be caught by this. Examples could be:

- losing internet connection
- losing power
- server endpoint being down

If you want consistency in this, you have to back it up with something server-side, that "expires" sessions that have not been heard from in x minutes.

So my suggestion:

1. Set flag to 1 when user enters page.
2. Implement the code you already have to update flag to 0.
3. Run a server function (using hangfire for background jobs could be an option) and update all sessions with flag 1 to 0 when it has not been active for x minutes.

Comment: is there any chance to get that event when user leave the page instead of setting fix time

Comment: You are on the right track with beforeunload, if that is what you mean. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event