# Before page leave event and back button

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events, browser-history

I am trying to bind an event on before leaving a page, but except, when the back button is pressed.
This is my code for the event:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {

    if(something){
        // do my custom code
    }
};
```

It works, but it binds and when the back button is pressed. This a normal logic, of course, but I need to find a way to check, is it back button pressed inside `onbeforeunload`. Something like this:

```
if(something && !isBackButton){
        // do my custom code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `onbeforeunload` will work better for your situation. You can check [intercept-page-exit-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event#1704783)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    isBackButton = false; 
    window.onbeforeunload = backHandler;
});

function backHandler() {
    if (isBackButton) {
        // do something's
    }
}

$("button.back").click(function() {
    isBackButton = true;
});
```

The above code checks the `isBackButton` variable if it's true then it will execute your code. Whenever click on back button value is changed, `isBackButton` variable is set to true.

Comment: Yes, sry it is `onbeforeunload `. The question edited.

Comment: @gdfgdfg You can use a global boolean variable if you pressed the back button.

Comment: The problem is that `onbeforeunload` fires first and that variable is always `false`.

Comment: I just an example of how to handle your case.