# Pass or return JSON Object from jQuery GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function that makes a GET request for a nested JSON object. The object is returned successfully but you can't access the other objects within the returned object.

the object looks like this :

```
{
    "student": {
        "hobbies": ["reading", "dancing", "music"], 
        "subjects": ["english", "maths", "science"]
    }
}
```

and this is the function :

```
var superObject = {

    getData: function(obj) {
        $.get(obj.target, function(callbackObject) {
            // It works fine if i log callbackObject
            // console.log(callbackObject);
            return callbackObject;
        }
    },

    useData: function() {
        var data = superObject.getData({'target': 'file.json'});
        var hobbies = data.student.hobbies;
        console.log(hobbies); // This fails and returns nothing.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're returning `callbackObject` from your $.get **callback**, and not from your `getData` function.  $.get is **asynchronous**, so its callback will not fire until long after `getData()` has finished.  That's why you're seeing undefined.

What about something like:

```
var superObject = {
    getReuslts: {},

    getData: function(obj) {
        $.get(obj.target, function(callbackObject) {
            getReuslts = callbackObject;
            this.useData();
        }
    },

    useData: function() {
        var hobbies = getReuslts.student.hobbies;
        console.log(hobbies); 
    }
}
```

Of course this would create a temporal dependency between useData and getData.  Why not create this object in a function so you can add some encapsulation?

```
funcition getSuperObject = {
    var result = {};
    var getReuslts = {};

    function useData() {
        var hobbies = getReuslts.student.hobbies;
        console.log(hobbies); 
    }

    result.getData = function(obj) {
        $.get(obj.target, function(callbackObject) {
            getReuslts = callbackObject;
            useData();
        });
    };
    return result;
}
```

Or supply your own callback:

```
var superObject = {    
    getData: function(obj, callback) {
        $.get(obj.target, function(callbackObject) {
            if (callback)
                callback(calbackObject);
        });
    }
}
```

And then

```
superObject.getData({'target': 'file.json'}, function(result) {
    var hobbies = result.student.hobbies;
    console.log(hobbies); // This fails and returns nothing.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to **asynchronous** Ajax behaviour, you need to pass a callback function to execute once the data retrieved via Ajax is available; something like:

```
getData: function(obj, callback) {
    $.get(obj.target, function(callbackObject) {
        callback.call(null, callbackObject);
    }
}

useData: function() {
    superObject.getData({'target': 'file.json'}, function(data) {
        var hobbies = data.student.hobbies;
    });
}
```

Comment: You logic worked for me. I just read a little about **asynchronous** and it helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` works *asynchronously*: you call it, then the browser goes off to make the request. *Meanwhile, your code continues running*. When the browser gets the response from the server, it invokes the callback function you provided passing it the results.

This means that when `getData` runs, it will return "almost immediately" and *the request started by `$.get` will still be in progress in the background*. So, `getData` cannot return anything meaningful to its caller because it can only *schedule* a requestl; it cannot know what the result will end up being.

So it follows that you cannot call `getData` like this:

```
var data = superObject.getData({'target': 'file.json'});
```

What you need to do instead is put the code that depends on the response inside the callback:

```
$.get(obj.target, function(data) {  
    var hobbies = data.student.hobbies;   
    console.log(hobbies); // This will now work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your variables is only in your function
You can try to set the variable hobbies out of your structure, and set it's value inside of your function

```
var hobbies; //global scope
var superObject = { 
getData: function(obj) {
$.get(obj.target, function(callbackObject) {
    // It works fine if i log callbackObject
    // console.log(callbackObject);
    return callbackObject;
}},

useData: function() {
var data = superObject.getData({'target': 'file.json'});
 hobbies= data.student.hobbies; 
//set it's value
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning in the callback handler.  So your result is sent to the callback dispatcher which drops your result. What you need to do is attach your processing code to the get callback:

```
getData: function(obj) { return $.getJSON(obj.target); },
useData: function() {
  getData({ target : 'file.json'}).then(function(results) {
    var hobbies = results.student.hobbies;
    console.log(hobbies);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your asynchronous AJAX call to be synchronous. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, mainly the "async" option.

See this discussion:

[Ajax jquery synchronous callback success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572610/ajax-jquery-synchronous-callback-success)