# why class variable throws undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a class, constructor and some functions, like below. in my getData function, I see `this.data` is populated once the api call is made, but when it gets to the `showData` function `this.data` is undefined. what am i missing here?

```
(function(){
  class foo{
   constructor (){
     this.data=[]; 
     this.btn = document.getElementById("btn")
     this.btn.addEventlistener('click', this.showData);
     this.getData(); 
   }
   getData(){
       $.ajax({
         url : 'someapi',
         type:'get',
         datatype : 'application/json',
         success : (results) => {
             this.data = results;
         }
       ); 
   }
   showData(){
      $.each(this.data, (item) => {
         console.log(item); 
      });
   }
  }
  new foo(); 
})();
```

Comment: you are missing the idea of asynchronous function

Comment: @mister jojo - thanks. can you give me some tips on how can i fix this

Comment: https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Comment: Does this answer your question? [on submit ajax result undefine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997857/on-submit-ajax-result-undefine)

Comment: @Mister Jojo - I think,  I understand the issue, but not sure how I can fix it.

Comment: promises -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise